# Brown representability theorem

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I am looking for quite a detailed proof of Brown representability theorem roughly along the lines of this sketch [https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/BrownRepresentability.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/BrownRepresentability.pdf) .
Any reference suggestions?

Comment: You'll find a proof in $\S$7.7 of Spanier's *Algebraic Topology*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at chapter 9 (especially Theorem 9.12) of

> Switzer, Robert M. Algebraic Topology - Homotopy and Homology. Springer, 2017

or at chapter 7 (especially Theorem 7.7.14) of

> Spanier, Edwin H. Algebraic topology. Springer Science & Business Media, 1989.